# Move ERC 721 Tokens to a different contract

Tags: contract-development, erc-721

imagine that I've a contract with 200 token already minted, now I see a mistake in the contract or I want to add a new functionality, how could I move all those tokens to a new contract?

Thank you

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the contract.

If the contract is upgradable then it is just updating the contract.

If it is not upgradable, you can implement in the new contract a way to migrate from the old one. Another option is to make the migration in batches.

Comment: In batches means to create all tokens again in the new contract and transfer them to their "old" owners?

Comment: @Cryptodev Yes, doing an airdrop to the owners. Probably you want to stop the old token and take and snapshot before doing that.